# SVN resolve problem: svn: warning: '#!/bin' is not a working copy

Tags: svn

I'm working with a main trunk and several branches. At one point, I have added a file (script) to the trunk, merged it throughout the rest of the branches (but didn't commit the branch changes).

Then I modified again the script and when I merged throughout the rest of the branches, SVN reported tree conflicts.

```
A  +  C experimentation.sh
      >   local add, incoming add upon merge
```

When trying to resolve (either with --accept 'working', 'theirs-full','mine-full'), I get an unbelievable:

```
svn: warning: '#!/bin' is not a working copy
```

where #!/bin/bash is, of course, the first line in the script file.

So far I've been unsuccessful in getting rid of this problem, so I can't make further commits. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that at some point the contents of the script got into the command line (through <) and caused mess... ?

Comment: Hi @pmod. That could be plausible, but why would only the script file get <-ed? This is almost 2 months ago, but what I remember is that I was just issuing basic commands e.g. svn commit (the whole folder).

Answer (score 0):

When svn says something is not a working copy, it means you are applying svn commands on a folder that is not a working copy ( or part of it) - ie doesn't have the `.svn` meta files.

I am not able to replicate you exact situation, but, delete the `#!/bin` folder in your working copy ( which you don't need of course!) and try the operations.

Comment: Hi @manojlds. Thanks for the answer. The problem I was having was that in my working copy I had a script file which started with `#!/bin`. So, there was no folder, but a file with that particular first line... After a commit, that script entered a conflict state and SVN treated this in an unfortunate manner (as described in my original message).